# using embedded Foreach loops to cross-reference arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to take two lists (arrays) of numbers, and use Foreach loops in PHP to create a third array containing all the common numbers. Feel like I have hit a roadblock as far as understanding the logic, can anyone out there make sense of what I've got and what is wrong?

```
<?php
$cardOutcome = array();

$explodeCalled = explode(",", $card_detail['calledNumbers']);
$explodeCard = explode(",", $card_detail['cardNumbers']);

foreach($explodeCard as $card)
{
    foreach($explodeCalled as $called)
    {
        if($called == $card)
        {
            $cardOutcome[] = $called;
        }
    }
}

print_r($cardOutcome);
?>
```

The array values and outcome of the print_r are below

```
$explodeCard = 2, 5, 1, 11, 4, 25, 19, 28, 21, 18, 32, 37, 38, 41, 40, 50, 55, 49, 56, 57, 75, 73, 61, 72, 74 

$explodeCalled = 3, 70, 39, 6, 45, 43, 9, 48, 54, 51, 49, 33, 21, 1, 65, 71, 75, 15, 50, 36, 55, 14, 13, 7, 4, 67, 74, 26, 8, 32, 22, 28, 62, 57, 56, 38, 12, 2, 59, 40, 27, 69, 18, 20, 42, 44, 37, 46, 72, 60, 11, 58, 66, 29, 30, 35, 52, 25, 47, 10, 61, 5, 23, 73, 53, 34, 41, 

$cardOutcome = Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 1 [3] => 11 [4] => 4 [5] => 25 [6] => 28 [7] => 21 [8] => 18 [9] => 32 [10] => 37 [11] => 38 [12] => 41 [13] => 40 [14] => 50 [15] => 55 [16] => 49 [17] => 56 [18] => 57 [19] => 75 [20] => 73 [21] => 61 [22] => 72 [23] => 74 )
```

The $outcome array seems to simple be printing the "card" values. I feel like I have made a blatant logical misstep. And ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try array_intersect (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$explodeCalled = explode(",", $card_detail['calledNumbers']);
$explodeCard = explode(",", $card_detail['cardNumbers']);
$cardOutcome = array_intersect($explodeCalled,$explodeCard);
```